# LWC Display detailed Error

Tags: lightning-web-components, error

I have an LWC that deletes a record.  There is a trigger that prevents that record from being deleted if it is linked to some other records.  When I try to delete one of these records, I get a generic error (Error deleting record
An error occurred while trying to update the record. Please try again.) I would like to get the error I coded in the trigger.  The LWC code is below:

```
deleteRecord(currentRow.Id)
    .then(() => {
        this.dispatchEvent(
            new ShowToastEvent({
                title: 'Success',
                message: 'Record deleted',
                variant: 'success'
            })
        );
        this.closeHandlerParent();
        this.isLoading = false; 
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log('2 B  im in deleteGs error' + JSON.stringify(error));
        this.dispatchEvent(
            new ShowToastEvent({
                title: 'Error deleting record',
                message: error.body.message,
               // message: error.message.erors,
                variant: 'error'
            })
        );
        this.isLoading = false; 
    });
```

Comment: Are you using [`addError()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_exceptions.htm) to set the error on the record being deleted?

Comment: You need to use the ldsUtils to simply error, here is a blog post I have written on [Simplify error handling in Lightning Web Components
](https://www.forcetrails.com/2020/10/simplify-error-handling-in-lwc.html).

Comment: Frank - Could you provide the code in the trigger relevant to throwing the error?

Comment: Thanks Rahul.  I got the class working and I can console.log to see the validation coming back.  but when I try to use that result in the message: reduceErrors(error)  I'm not getting the detailed message?  thanks!

Comment: I figured it out... I  had to convert the error to a string with toString()